# POST Multiple Row to Database with fill out only one form on RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller

I'm try to develop one rails application.

When I fill out the form, I'm getting this parameter.

```
"daysoff"=>{"offdate"=>"06/08/2015, 06/09/2015, 06/10/2015, 06/11/2015, 06/12/2015", "assign_id"=>"3", "user_id"=>"2"}
```

Here is my index controller,

```
def index
    @people = User.all
    @user = User.current

    @daysoff = Daysoff.new

  end
```

My table coloumns are offdate (date), user_id (int), :assign_id (int), so i want to post each date for one row and other column values must be same.

How should i write create controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
off_dates = params["daysoff"]["offdate"].try(:split,',')
off_dates.each do |off_date|
    days_off = Daysoff.new
    days_off.offdate = Date.strptime(off_date.strip, "%m/%d/%Y")
    days_off.user_id = params["user_id"]
    days_off.assign_id = params["assign_id"]
    days_off.save!
end
```